# batch script to overwrite a file

Tags: batch-file

```
set path=folderX
( for /F "delims=" %%a in (!path!/file.txt) do (
   set "line=%%a"
   if !line!==Status=ON (
   set line=Status=OFF
   echo !line!
   )

)) > "!path!/file.txt"
```

what this script is suppose to do is open `file.txt` in `folderX`, replace the line `Status=ON` with `Status=OFF`. But when I run the code it says `System cannot find the file folderX/file.txt`, if I look at the file it turns into a blank file. If I assign a different name (`file2.txt`) then it works and `file2.txt` is correctly edited and placed in the right folder. Why is this? I thought it would overwrite the original by using `>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are reading from the same file you are writing to.  Use a different filename and add a rename or move command as the last line.

Comment: thought I could just overwrite without an issue, I guess not. it now saves as a different name, deletes original and renames new. works now. thanks